# Vertically center the showing images on a fixed height Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Maybe this is one of the toughest challenges, how can I vertically align in the middle the showing images on this fixed height Bootstrap *(v3.3.5)* carousel? I'd tried to `display` some classes as a `table-cell` and `vertical-align` them to `middle` but there's still a problem, the sliding image will just be vertically aligned when sliding-completed or when `.active` but it will also placed the image on the right side instead to the center.

```css
/* The styles that I tried.
.carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
.carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
.carousel-inner > .item.active {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
} */

.carousel-inner > .item {
    height: 150px;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x65" alt="350x65">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Item 1</h3>
                    <p>Not vertically center..</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350x150">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Item 2</h3>
                    <p>The image height is just fit..</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="200x100">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Item 3</h3>
                    <p>Not vertically center..</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.carousel-inner .item img {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can position the element absolutely ensuring the parent element is position relative so that the child element respects it's position to it.

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Look at your edition https://jsfiddle.net/3329o5z7/ but still no down-vote for `translateY(-50%)` browser compatibility.

Comment: sorry typo on the translate but looks like you got it :)

Comment: I forgot to test it without a typo https://jsfiddle.net/3329o5z7/1/ and it works like http://stackoverflow.com/a/31146558/4883372 .

Comment: @5ervant works on jsfiddle but get jumped images on the real browser

Answer (score 1):

Set `position:absolute`, all sides to `0` and `margin:auto`.

Here you go:

```css
/* The styles that I tried.
.carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
.carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
.carousel-inner > .item.active {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
} */

.carousel-inner > .item {
  height: 150px;
}
.carousel-inner img {
  margin: auto;
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x65" alt="350x65">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Item 1</h3>
          <p>Not vertically center..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350x150">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Item 2</h3>
          <p>The image height is just fit..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="200x100">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Item 3</h3>
          <p>Not vertically center..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're looking for: should probably test it with actual images just to make sure it looks right.

```
.carousel-inner .item img {
margin: 0px auto;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
```

}